# Testing ibm data server connection with testconn40.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2015, informix

Hello i am getting error when trying to test my connection to informix server. Steps that i did:

1.Install IBM Data Server Client

2.Install IBM Data Server Runtime Client

3.after that , with cmd i navigated to the Data Server Driver Package\bin\netf40
and executed this three lines of code

```
gacutil /i IBM.Data.DB2.dll
gacutil /i IBM.Data.DB2.Entity.dll
gacutil /i IBM.Data.Informix.dll
```

4.Insalled IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio(i have 2015  version)

**What i want to do is replace the old odbc way of connecting to informix server with the use of the reference IBM.Data.DB2 or IBM.Data.Informix**

But before doing anything more, when testing my connection with testconn40.exe i got communication error in step 3. Here is the code i am runing in cmd

```
testconn40.exe -ids database=ibis2;server=192.168.1.2:9088;userid=informix;password=informix
```

And this gives me this lines of code

```
using Common Informix .NET provider
Step 1: Printing version info
        .NET Framework version: 4.0.30319.42000
        Factory for invariant name IBM.Data.Informix verified
        IBM.Data.Informix from DbFactory is the Common Informix .NET provider
        Common Informix .NET provider version: 9.7.4.4
        Common Informix .NET provider file version: 11.1.2020.4
        Capability bits: ALLDEFINED
        Build: s1706091900
        Warning, failed load of DbFactory for:IBM.Data.Informix.11.1.0
        Warning, failed load of DbFactory for:IBM.Data.Informix.11.1.1011
        IBM Database Add-ins assembly version: 9.1.0.0
        IBM Database Add-ins file version: 11.1.2020.5
        Elapsed: 0,248704
Step 2: DB2DSDRIVER_CFG_PATH env var: unset
        Validating db2dsdriver.cfg against db2dsdriver.xsd schema file
        File searched at C:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2\DB2COPY1\cfg\db2dsdriver.cfg  missing. Nothing to validate
        Elapsed: 0,0070187
Step 3: Connecting using Common Informix provider "database=ibis2;server=192.168.1.2:9088;userid=informix;password=informix"

Unable to open socket to server:
ERROR [08001] [IBM] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "192.168.1.2".  Communication function detecting the error: "recv".  Protocol specific error code(s): "*", "*", "0".  SQLSTATE=08001
Some things to consider:
- is the port number correctly specified
  50000 is the default for LUW servers
    svcename dbm cfg parm for LUW servers
  446 is the only port for iSeries servers, default for zSeries
- for a LUW server, is the TCPIP listener started
  db2set DB2COMM=TCPIP, db2stop / db2start
- for an Informix server, ensure DRDA listener is started
  and you are using DRDA port vs the SQLI port
Test failed.
```

Comment: Anyone please ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your IDS server enabled for DRDA connections?
Native Informix CSDK uses the SQLI protocol for communication, but the IBM Data Server Driver use DRDA.
That error you see in the testconn40 output usually means that you are trying to connect to the SQLI listener, not to the DRDA one.

Basically, you need to define an alias (DBSERVERALIASES) in your onconfig file pointing to a entry in the sqlhosts file with "drsoctcp" as the protocol.

If you have done a default installation it should be already there, so just use that port/service rather than the olsoctcp one.

Comment: I think that i dont have DRDA enabled, will check that , thanks :)